# Ember Data: Delete a record without removing it from view before commit

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Take the following:

```
FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  # Model is set, view is rendered, button is clicked
  someDeleteAction: ->
    # Object is destroyed & removed from view
    @get('content').deleteRecord();

    # Uh-oh... error happens here, but object
    # remains 'deleted' according to ember 
    @get('content.transaction').commit();
```

Is there a way to prevent an object from being destroyed and removed from the view?

Bonus points: On a scale of 1 to Chinese Water Torture... how much fun is `ember-data`?

Comment: I think view must be removed after the server returns success for the delete action, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: No... as soon as I call `model.deleteRecord()` it's gone, even before the server has been contacted.

Comment: Anyway... I'm pretty sick of ember basically because of ember-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

Override `DS.Model.deleteRecord` so it contacts the server first, then `commit` the transaction.

Comment: Can you post your solution?